# FormData is posted on API, still client side gets "Network Error" in axios while uploading File

Tags: express, react-native, axios, expo, multer

I'm trying to upload Image File to my Express API which uses multer file.
Postman is working correctly. Axios posts the data, but sends Network Error 
- node_modules/axios/lib/core/createError.js:16:24 in createError
- node_modules/axios/lib/adapters/xhr.js:87:25 in handleError
- ... 9 more stack frames from framework internals

Fetch also give error

```
handleChange(value) {
    this.setState({value});
}

async handleSubmit() {
    const date = this.state.chosenDate
    const value = this._form.getValue();
    var imageName = this.state.imageData.split('/').pop(-1)
    var image = {
        uri : this.state.imageData,
        type : 'image/jpeg' ,
        name : imageName
    }
    const body = { ...value , date : date, image : image}

    var formData  = new FormData();

    for(var name in body) {
        formData.append (name, body[name]);
    }

    console.log(formData)
    const url = IP + '/dummy'



    axios({
        method: 'post',
        url: url,
        data: formData,
        config: { headers: {'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data' }}
        })
        .then(function (response) {
            //handle success
            console.log(response);
        })
        .catch(function (response) {
            //handle error
            console.log(response);
        });


}
```

Comment: i'm using React-Native from Expo

Comment: Have you find any solution?